# Gradle resource processing - properties in maven, dotted manner

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build-process

I am about to migrate the maven project into the gradle project. It is almost working excluding the matter with the properties file. I have following src/main/resources/app.properties file:

```
project1.property1=${project1.property1}
project1.property2=${project1.property2}
project2.property1=${project2.property1}
project2.property2=${project2.property2}
```

I have tried in the beginning to make sth like that:

```
processResources {
    fileMatching('*.properties') {
        expand project.properties
    }
}
```

It doesn't work because all properties are written in dotted, maven-like manner.

I have tried also following solution:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-way-of-processing-resources-with-maven-notation/4948

It doesn't fail (build), but also it does not work (does not substitute properties).

What am I doing wrongly and what should I do to properly filter properties?

Comment: Why don't you use gradle style, I mean with `@`?

Comment: Because it's a huge project with the long history. I would never finish rewriting the project, unfortunately. The '@' sign is no problem, the problem is a dotted style. 
Existing problem - even with '@' sign
     Could not copy file '${PROJECT_PATH}\src\main\resources\app.properties' to '${PROJECT_PATH}\build\resources\main\app.properties'